# Laravel Eloquent Relation Column Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I have two models in Laravel User and Order User can have many Orders and an Order can have only one User.

I have defined the one to many relation but it gives me an unknown column error when performing this query:

```
App\Order::find(1)->users;
```

I'm Using Laravel Latest version.

```
//This is Order Model

class Order extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
}


class User extends Authenticatable
{
  public function Order()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    } 
}
```

Comment: How have you defined your tables? Show your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each order belongs to one user add this to Order model :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

and get users:

```
    App\Order::find(1)->users()->get()
```

Comment: your welcome,if it works why did you give me negative?

Comment: He can't give negative though he has only one point. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For One to Many relationship in laravel you have to define the relation on both sides as follow:

**User Model**

```
class User Model
{
  public function orders()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
  } 
}
```

And now we have to define inverse of the above relation as follow:

**Order Model**

```
class Order extends Model
{

 public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding brackets:

`App\Order::find(1)->users()->get()`

This should fix your error.

Comment: That would return a querybuilder relationship, and not the collection.